# What's the strategy called of brute forcing a program to crash with different inputs?

Tags: c++, testing, crash, code-coverage

I recall hearing about an effective testing strategy that helps find bugs in software.  It involved using another program to generate various inputs.  By trying thousands of different inputs, we hopefully cause the program to go down an execution path that it does not normally go down.  The goal being to get programs to crash, or throw exceptions, giving us insight to improve the quality of software.  I believe it was even had some kind of heuristic, where it was able to know whether it was getting somewhere different in the code based on the inputs it was sending.

I can't learn more about it, because I can't recall what this method of testing was called.

If it helps, I think it was mentioned in regards to C++.  Maybe it was a compiler extension.  I remember the speaker showing how he would write some kind of test rule, then the implementation, and then brute force it to show edge cases that he missed.

Comment: This sounds related to *code coverage* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage

Comment: @Galik Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called fuzz testing, you can find more info here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing

Comment: That's it.  Thank you.